# Inconsistent behaviour with TCP socket's recv() watermark on Linux

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I was delving into socket tuneables, and I encountered the `SO_RCVLOWAT` option, so I created a test-case to determine whether the watermark eliminated a specific issue I've had in developing servers before (namely premature data truncation:)

```
def run_server(host: str, port: int, low_watermark: int):
    sk_server = socket.socket()
    sk_server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
    sk_server.setsockopt(
        socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVLOWAT, low_watermark
    )
    sk_server.bind((host, port))
    sk_server.listen(1)
    cl_sockfd, cl_addr = sk_server.accept()
    print(f"connected to client, receiving at least {low_watermark}"
           " bytes of data")
    assert len(cl_sockfd.recv(low_watermark)) == low_watermark
    # *** never reached
    print("all good!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    host, port = "localhost", 6969
    watermark = 100
    thd_server = threading.Thread(
        target=run_server,
        args=(host, port, watermark)
    )
    thd_server.start()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    client = socket.socket()
    client.connect((host, port))

    fragment_1 = b"a" * (n := watermark // 2)
    fragment_2 = b"a" * (watermark - n)

    print("sending first fragment, and waiting 1 second")
    print("sent", client.send(fragment_1), "bytes")
    time.sleep(1)

    print("sending second fragment")
    print("sent", client.send(fragment_2), "bytes")
    print("done. waiting for server thread to finish")

    thd_server.join()
```

In short, the client sends exactly `watermark` bytes to the server which is configured to receive at least `watermark` bytes, however the principal issue is that the server hangs on the `cl_sockfd.recv(low_watermark)`.

As a sanity-check, I send a single fragment of size `watermark`, and of course this works as expected, and any single fragments below `watermark` are rejected. But, the curious observation I make is that with two fragments the only way the server will accept the `send()` is when the second fragment has size `watermark`, in which case the two fragments combine as expected, but the remainder length after `watermark` is discarded, **but** if I instead send three fragments, the first two of which combine to make length `watermark`, but the third fragment has size `watermark // 2` then it all works, but now the **third** fragment is discarded.

This does not make sense at all. Is there any explanation for this?

**Post-notes:**

1. I experimented by enabling `TCP_NODELAY` so that `send()` buffers are immediately flushed, to question whether Linux was post-maturely flushing the buffer (after the third fragment triggered a flush,) but behaviour remained identical
2. In the scenario of three fragments, totalling 104 bytes of data, no extraneous data is left to `recv()`, which is expected considering the watermark enforces a minimum, but then after sending the remaining amount to total `2*watermark` the `recv()` works perfectly as expected even though it's spread over two `send()`s, which again makes no sense considering it failed to receive the initial two fragments, despite them matching the same criteria.

Comment: XY problem. What is 'premature data truncation'?

Comment: @user207421 it's my description of whenever a client sends fragmented data with an insignificant time delay between, that still yet causes the server to treat the buffers as separate. it isn't however my motive for solving this issue.

Comment: You can't stop that from your end. Just keep reading until you get what you want.

Comment: @user207421 I'm aware of that solution, I have no issue with understanding how to reconcile fragmented data, my particular question is regarding why the behaviour of `recv()` is as it is.